# RXJava 2 called twice

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

Im still trying to use RXJava 2 for a polling service used by multiple subscribers. It works well except that it always called twice.

I tried using publish(1), take(1), share(), refCount(), etc but the results are always the same. Called twice or multiple time.

I still dont get it why its called twice. New subscribers should receive the latest emitted values and after only changed values (if the hashmap changed) returned as modified list.

My polling observable (Singleton)

```
public Observable<List<Light>> lightPolling = CallFactory
            .with(context)
            .getLights(MainApplication.lastaccespoint)
            .repeatWhen(o -> o.concatMap((Function<Object, ObservableSource<?>>) v -> Observable.timer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
            .filter(new MapPredicate<>())
            .distinctUntilChanged()

            .map(l -> {
                List<Light> lights = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Light> entry : l.entrySet()) {
                    Light light = entry.getValue();
                    light.setId(entry.getKey());
                    lights.add(light);
                }
                return lights;
            })
            // .replay(1)
            //    .distinct()
            //.publish()
            //.share()
            .compose(ReplayingShare.instance()); // its like .share(), just including the last result etc.
```

My Predicate for filtering if the hashmap is really changed. StringUtil.equalMap is just a simple method which compares two hashmaps which works well.

```
 class MapPredicate<T> implements Predicate<Map<String, T>> {

    private Map<String, T> lastMap;

    @Override
    public boolean test(Map<String, T> map) throws Exception {
        if (!StringHelper.equalMap(map, lastMap)) {
            Timber.d("Result in MapPredicate doesnt equals last result");
            lastMap = map;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally my Disposable which subscribes on the Observable.

```
lightsDisposable = LightManager
            .getInstance(context)
            .lightPolling
            .subscribeWith(new BulbsObserver());
```

Some more for testing

```
 LightManager.getInstance(context).lightPolling.debounce(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(lights -> Timber.d("Received light second Subscriber "+ lights.size()));
 LightManager.getInstance(context).lightPolling.debounce(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(lights -> Timber.d("Received light Third Subscriber "+ lights.size()));
```

And of course my Observer

```
private class BulbsObserver extends DisposableObserver<List<Light>> {

    @Override
    public void onNext(List<Light> newLights) {
        Timber.d("Received lights=" + newLights.size());
        lights.clear();
        lights.addAll(newLights);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        Timber.e(throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        Timber.d("onComplete called");
    }
}
```

Replaying Share is from Jack Wharton https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare

Answer (score 4):

`refCount()` subscribes (invokes subscribe function) whenever first subscriber comes, and unsubscribes after last one leaves. In case your subscribers come in sequence (i.e. reference count drops to zero between them) you shall experience multiple subscribes/unsubscribes to original source.

If you wish to subscribe only once and *never unsubscribe*, use `autoConnect()` instead of `refCount()`. For example:

```
hotObservable = coldObservable.replay(1).autoConnect();
```

Comment: afaik rxjava2 doesnt have refCount anymore. Instead its share() http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/refcount.html and this doesnt work.

Comment: It is there on `ConnectableObservable`: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observables/ConnectableObservable.html#refCount() `share()` is equivalent to `publish().refCount()`, so `refCount` is included in all your cases.

Comment: Thank you, but it should unsubscribe. It should only "subscribe" as soon as one subscriber is subscribed.  The  proper word is "cold observable", isnt it?

Comment: In your code everything above `replay` or `ReplayingShare` is *cold*. And it is gonna be re-subscribed every time reference count steps up from zero.

Comment: Thank you. Could you post an example how to use this?  Not fixing my code, just an example to understand how it should be.

Comment: Added to my answer.

Comment: For complement, there are some difference between `replay` and Jake's `ReplayingShare` basically you can't `autoDisconnect` from upstream if you use `autoConnect`. But somehow it's a larger topic which a single SO comment can not be cover. I recommend you write some demo to try it out.